# CEP issue while checkpointing."Could not find id for entry"

Tags: apache-flink, complex-event-processing

When checkpointing is turned on a simple CEP loop pattern

```
 private Pattern<Tuple2<Integer, SimpleBinaryEvent>, ?> alertPattern = Pattern.<Tuple2<Integer, SimpleBinaryEvent>>begin("start").where(checkStatusOn)
        .followedBy("middle").where(checkStatusOn).times(2)
        .next("end").where(checkStatusOn).within(Time.minutes(5))
```

I see failures.

SimpleBinaryEvent is

```
public class SimpleBinaryEvent implements Serializable {

private int id;
private int sequence;
private boolean status;
private long time;

public SimpleBinaryEvent(int id, int sequence, boolean status , long time) {
    this.id = id;
    this.sequence = sequence;
    this.status = status;
    this.time = time;
}
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public int getSequence() {
    return sequence;
}
public boolean isStatus() {
    return status;
}
public long getTime() {
    return time;
}
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    SimpleBinaryEvent that = (SimpleBinaryEvent) o;

    if (getId() != that.getId()) return false;
    if (isStatus() != that.isStatus()) return false;
    if (getSequence() != that.getSequence()) return false;
    return getTime() == that.getTime();
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    //return Objects.hash(getId(),isStatus(), getSequence(),getTime());
    int result = getId();
    result = 31 * result + (isStatus() ? 1 : 0);
    result = 31 * result + getSequence();
    result = 31 * result + (int) (getTime() ^ (getTime() >>> 32));
    return result;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "SimpleBinaryEvent{" +
            "id='" + id + '\'' +
            ", status=" + status +
            ", sequence=" + sequence +
            ", time=" + time +
            '}';
}
```

}

failure cause:

```
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Could not materialize checkpoint 2 for operator KeyedCEPPatternOperator -> Map (1/1).
... 6 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find id for entry: SharedBufferEntry(ValueTimeWrapper((1,SimpleBinaryEvent{id='1', status=true, sequence=95, time=1505503380000}), 1505503380000, 0),....
```

I am sure I have the equals() and hashCode() implemented the way it should be. I have tried the Objects.hashCode too. In other instances I have had CircularReference ( and thus stackOverflow ) on SharedBuffer.toString(), which again points to issues with references ( equality and what not ). Without checkpointing turned on it works as expected. I am running on a local cluster. Is CEP production ready ?

I am using 1.3.2 Flink

Comment: It looks very similar to http://apache-flink-user-mailing-list-archive.2336050.n4.nabble.com/Keyed-CEP-checkpoint-fails-td14795.html

Comment: If required I can reproduce from within a self contained junit, which is how I created it to begin with.

Comment: It would be great if you could post a JIRA with the self-contained Junit. I will have a look at it then.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for trying out the library and reporting this!

The library is under active development as more and more features are added to it. The 1.3 was the first release of the library with such rich semantics, so we expect to see 1) how people use it and 2) if there are any bugs. So I would say that it is not 100% production-ready but it is not far.

Now for the problem at hand, I suppose you are using RocksDB for checkpointing, right? The reason I am assuming that is that with RocksDB, at each watermark (in event time) you deserialize the necessary state (e.g. the `NFA`), process some events and then serialize it again before putting it back in RocksDB.

This is not the case for the filesystem state backend, where you only serialize the state upon checkpointing and you read it and deserialize it only upon recovery. So in this case, given that you said that without checkpointing your job works fine, you would only see this problem only after recovering from a failure.

The root of the problem can be either that `equals()`/`hashcode()` is buggy (which does not seem to be the case), or there is a problem on the way we serialize/deserialize the CEP state.

Could you also provide a minimal input sequence of events that produce this to happen? This will be really helpful in order to reproduce the problem.

Thanks a lot,
Kostas

Comment: I am running in a local mode as a junit as in a  LocalFlinkMiniCluster(config, false). Will get the test ready and submit. Have been slammed by other things.